# Ionic V3, Cordova chrome sockets udp error in error callback

Tags: android, cordova, sockets, ionic-framework, udp

The end-game for me is a UPnP provider that can query for devices on a network. I've tried several existing discovery plugins but they're broken and not maintained. If someone knows of a solution to that end the rest of this becomes moot.

As for my issue: I am stuck writing my UDP socket provider. I am using Ionic v3 and cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp@1.3.0. I am testing on an Android. I have not tried iOS.

I can .create() and .close() a socket just fine. .bind() and .send() calls always fail. Initially the calls faulted, reporting this error:

```
Error in Error callbackId: ChromeSocketsUdp1682499592 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

Inspecting the UDP plugin, I found a require() for cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-runtime.runtime but that wasn't installed. So, I installed that. The error callbacks stopped failing outright but their return values are now undefined. To be pedantic, the .bind() response to the ionic code layer is totally undefined but .send() has a cordova wrapper that assembles a result which is now this:

```
{bytesSent: 0, resultCode: undefined}
```

The undefined resultCode is due to the empty error coming from the android platform code. The relevant citation looks likes this:

```
var fail = callback && function(error) {
    var sendInfo = {
        bytesSent: 0,
        resultCode: error.resultCode
    };
    callbackWithError(error.message, callback, sendInfo);
};
exec(win, fail, 'ChromeSocketsUdp', 'send', [socketId, address, port, data]);
```

The exec() function is providing 'fail()' to the platform code which is getting called, passing nothing back to the app layer. I compared the UDP platform code with the TCP platform code since the TCP plugin is used elsewhere in this same project without issue. The only difference in the TCP and UDP platform send functions called by exec() would be TCP's check for a connection. Otherwise, the structure and variable names are identical.

Having to include the *apps-runtime plugin was a hack-cident. It isn't part of any prior installation and prep instructions I've read. I'm fairly sure I or my project have run astray somehow.

My manifest.json includes but is not limited to this:

```
  "sockets": {
    "udp": {
      "send": ["*"],
      "bind": ["*"]
    }
  }
```

My plugin list includes but is not limited to these:

```
cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-common 1.0.7 "Chrome Apps Common Utils"
cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-runtime 2.0.0 "Chrome App Runtime"
cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp 1.3.7 "Chrome Apps Sockets TCP API"
cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp 1.3.0 "Chrome Apps Sockets UDP API"
```

using `adb logcat` at the time the callbacks fail does not appear to return anything interesting. No permission complaints. Just the callstack pointing me to the places descibed above and my litany of console.log() firings.

I have `declare var chrome;` at the top of my provider document but I am actually invoking calls using `(<any>window).chrome.sockets.udp.`. I have verified the typeof .bind() and .send() is function and that chrome.sockets.udp != 'undefined'.

My onReceive and onReceiveError listeners are registered in my provider's constructor.

Halp?

Comment: Decided to adopt and fix a broken SSDP plugin. I am not pursuing a solution to this issue.

Comment: which plugin? trying to work with UDP

Comment: For SSDP I started with and modified: https://github.com/scottdermott/cordova-plugin-discovery. The public code for android in this plugin is broken. My purpose for trying UDP was to implement the functionality of the above plugin with an app level provider. Since I was not able to resolve the topic issue I opted to fix the plugin. I don't have general UDP advice.